# KeyDown Event is not being fired

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have added on top of my form `PictureBox & Panel` and docked them to the form, and I have registered the `KeyDown` event, but it's not firing, why is that if the `Form` is the `Container` for both `Controls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`. By setting this property the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

In your form constructor

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```